# Search a list of string with a given substring in python

Tags: python, string, list, search

I'm developing a dictionary kind of application using python. In my code, there is a list which consists of sorted set of strings. when a user give some text, I want to get all the string starting with the given string. In other words, I just want to suggest words while user is typing.

Example : If user typed the word "sub", I want to take all the string from the list starting with the substring "sub".

Can anyone give me an algorithm to do this? Thanks all.

Comment: this features is usually referred to as *auto-complete*; however, if you query an Internet search engine for "python and "auto-complete", most of the results will relate to auto-complete python syntax for text editors.

Comment: Consider Huffman coding as food for thought on this problem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332028/what-is-an-efficient-search-algorithm-to-provide-auto-completion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size of the list, you could just iterate through it and use the [startswith()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) string function to get the result. If that's too slow, a common way is to use a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a trie data structure, which is perfect for what you seek. Your code needs to handle heavy read/retrieval. Look up trie. if you need implementation let me know.